# Python shutil.rmtree call taking an extremely long time

Tags: python, unix

I currently have a Python program calls `shutil.rmtree` when it finishes to delete a large number of files that is creates as it executes. This call is taking in the order of ~20+ seconds. I have profiled this using cProfile and almost all of this time is spent on posix.remove calls.

If I don't delete these files as part of the Python program but instead call `rm -rf` on the folder after the program is finished executing, the `rm -rf` executes in <5 seconds.

Is there something in particular that may be causing this huge difference in execution time?

Answer (score 2):

`shutil.rmtree` makes a system call of `os.stat` on every file entry it traverses to determine if it's a file or a directory, which is a massive waste of time since that information is already obtained when a directory is listed.

This information is something that the `os.walk` function takes advantage of (see [PEP-471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) for details), with which you can implement `rmtree` yourself:

```
import os
def rmtree(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
        for file in files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
        for dir in dirs:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, dir))
    os.rmdir(directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source for `rmtree`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/shutil.py#L450), it has a lot of python code that executes in addition to the minimal amount of native code. A lot of it is also string processing, which makes several small ephemeral objects. I don't have a profile handy right now, but my guess is that much of the time is spent [in the loop body of `_rmtree_safe_fd`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/shutil.py#L406).